# Installing TWRP using Odin will erase data or not?

Tags: twrp, odin

My Samsung Note 3 Neo is stuck on Samsung screen. I need the backup of data, but I dont have any recovery other than the default recovery (having options: Apply update from ADB/External storage, Factory Reset, Wipe Cache Partition etc)

I am going to install TWRP custom recovery on it using Odin.

1. Will this installation using Odin erase my data?
2. Can Odin be helpful in some other way, to take backup of mobile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It will not wipe data unless you explicitly choose to erase NAND (after which your phone would end up bricked).
2. Odin only flashes images into the device - it doesn't read data out. You're on the right track about using TWRP to reclaim data, just be sure to install one made for your device.

Comment: +1 you beat me to it. Saw it earlier and delayed answering

Comment: Will my Contacts and Messages be not erased, also?

Comment: I have found on some websites that Flashing Custom Recovery will cause unlocking of bootloader, which wipes out all the data. Is it true?

Comment: For earlier Samsung devices, bootloader is unlocked by default. You will lose nothing unless you do something extra at your own fault (e.g. misclicking wipe data inside the recovery).